# Star Rating in Dialogbox won't change saved value

Tags: java, android

```
                // Custom Dialog Box
                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert);
                final View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.completed, null);
                ImageButton imgForm = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.RateButton);

                mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                mBuilder.setView(mView);

                final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();                              // Dialogbox appears



                // Interest Rating
                final AlertDialog.Builder nBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder( MainActivity.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert);
                final View nView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.intrst, null);
                Save_Intrst = (Button) nView.findViewById(R.id.SaveIntrst);

                nBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                nBuilder.setView(nView);
                final AlertDialog dilog = nBuilder.create();

                // LongPress Image Button
                imgForm.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View view){

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        dilog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                        dilog.show();           // Dialogbox appears
                        return true;
                    }
                });


                Save_Intrst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    String IntrstLvl;
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){

                        RatingBar rBar = (RatingBar)nView.findViewById(R.id.ratingStar);

                        IntrstLvl = Integer.toString(rBar.getNumStars());

                        addData(IntrstLvl);

                        dilog.dismiss();
                        Log.d(TAG,"Dismissed");
                    }
                });
```

Whenever I select "save" within the Save_Intrst it saves 5 stars regardless of what I choose. I'm still fairly new to Android development and have been java coding for a bit now.

This is just a snippet of code of the project and I believe it will be enough, it shows my submit button, the submit button will launch a dialog box that will have a secret button in an image (ImgForm) the image doesn't show but that's not the problem, after long pressing it will launch another dialog that has a 5 Star Rating Bar and a Save button, this is used for rating after the person completes the previous requirements. The rating will always save "5" regardless of what was inserted, even after a reinstall of app onto the device.

Answer (score 1):

`getNumStars()` will tell you the maximum number of stars shown and will always be 5 as you have defined it. If you want the actual selected rating, you will need `getRating()`. See [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getNumStars()).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **rBar.getRating()**

```
RatingBar rBar = (RatingBar)nView.findViewById(R.id.ratingStar);

IntrstLvl = Integer.toString(rBar.getRating());
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html

You are calling `getNumStars()` which according to the documentation "Returns the number of stars shown." which means the total number of stars a user can select.  You should instead be checking `getRating()` which returns the number of stars currently selected.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getRating()